# View Uploaded PDF in Lightgallery

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, lightgallery

I used lightgallery for preview of uploaded image it works well. The same way when I try to open uploaded pdf in lighgallery it is not showing up. But I am able to view pdf when given hardcoded path value in data-src.

```
img#exeImg.height-100.load-pdf(src="/custom/img/nodata.svg" data-iframe="true"  data-src="/custom/img/Manual.pdf")

$('.load-pdf').lightGallery({
  selector: 'this'
});
```

But when try to use uploaded base 64 pdf it is not working

```
function previewDocuments(input,imgId){
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $(imgId).attr('src', "/custom/img/fileuploaded.svg");  
      $(imgId).attr('data-src',e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```